# Bash script - While condition with if/then

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop

So I am having a problem understanding how to loop a condition. Here is my example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " Which team do you prefer, FSU or UF?"
read -r TEAM
while [ "$TEAM" != "FSU" || "UF" ]; do
        echo "That was not one of your choices. Please choose FSU or UF"
if [ "$TEAM" == "FSU" ]; then
        echo "You chose the better team"
else [ "$TEAM" == "UF" ];
        echo "You did NOT choose the better team"
fi
done
```

Basically, what I am looking for is user input and if that condition isn't met it would loop back until the correct input is met.
What am I doing wrong? In this example I get an error back if I choose an input outside of FSU or Uf as:

"./test.sh: line 4: [: missing `]'
./test.sh: line 4: UF: command not found"

However, if I choose FSU or UF I get the same error.

Comment: `[ "$TEAM" != "FSU" || "UF" ]` is not a valid syntax. You have to compare `$TEAM` against each possible string

Comment: The major problem is the while line should read `while [ "$TEAM" != "FSU" || "$TEAM" != "UF" ]; do`. Other than that, you are terminating your loop (`done`) at the wrong place.

Comment: Thirdly, looking at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florida%E2%80%93Florida_State_football_rivalry#Game_results), it seems the results of your `if` clause are backwards, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " Which team do you prefer, FSU or UF?"
read -r TEAM
while [[ "$TEAM" != "FSU" && "$TEAM" !=  "UF" ]]; do
        echo "That was not one of your choices. Please choose FSU or UF"
        read -r TEAM
done
if [[ "$TEAM" == "FSU" ]]; then
        echo "You chose the better team"
else [[ "$TEAM" == "UF" ]];
        echo "You did NOT choose the better team"
fi
```

Changes:

Look at `Done` location, You need to exit the `while loop` after the user input validation pass.

You need to ask for user's input after he fails with required input. hence the `read -r TEAM` in `while loop`.

Your logical comparison was `OR` instead of `AND` in the `while loop`.

Comment: Ok. That work. Thanks. I had been told by someone else on a different site that you would embed the if/then/else statement inside the while loop. I was trying that but it would not work.
So, I wrote my script a little different from yours and it still works. I did not double bracket the if/then/else statement.

Comment: You can do that, depends on your situtation, If you want the `if else` gets validated on each `while loop`, you put that inside your `loop block`, but thats not what we want right now.